# How to make and send a print screen to a FTP server without save the file? My working code save the files to HDD

Tags: c++, ftp, gdi+

Before to made this post I searched and trying 4 days all things,like https://www.codeproject.com/kb/gdi-plus/memimage.aspx, but I am new in programming.

This code (not mine), made a print screen, save to a file and then are sent to a ftp server. I want to do this without save the files to HDD, from memory to FTP.

```
// The print-screen and save to file (jpg) code:

wstring wtmp;
tmp =   sDate + pictureName + ".jpeg";
wtmp = ToStringW(tmp);
screenName = wtmp.c_str();
ftpScreenName = wtmp.c_str();
fileToRemove = tmp.c_str();
using namespace Gdiplus;
GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;

GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
{
HDC scrdc, memdc;
HBITMAP membit;
scrdc = ::GetDC(0);
int Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
int Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(scrdc);
membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(scrdc, Width, Height);
HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(memdc, membit);
BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, scrdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(membit, NULL);

EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
ULONG quality;

CLSID clsid;
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
encoderParameters.Count = 1;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Guid = EncoderQuality;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Type = EncoderParameterValueTypeLong;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].NumberOfValues = 1;

// Save the image as a JPEG with quality level 80.
quality = 80;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Value = &quality;

int result;
result = bitmap.Save(screenName, &clsid); //saving the file to HDD

//send to ftp with given info
saveFTP(server, user, password, ftpScreenName, screenName);
}
GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
```

// And here the FTP client part:

```
bool saveFTP(LPCWSTR l_server, LPCWSTR l_user, LPCWSTR l_pass, LPCWSTR l_ftpfile, LPCWSTR l_screen)
{
HINTERNET internet = InternetOpen(L"tester", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
HINTERNET inter = InternetConnect(internet, l_server, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, l_user, l_pass, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
bool result;
result = FtpPutFile(inter, l_screen, l_ftpfile, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
InternetCloseHandle(inter);
InternetCloseHandle(internet);
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`FtpOpenFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384166.aspx) and [`InternetWriteFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385128.aspx) instead of `FtpPutFile()`.  This is explicitly stated in the [`FtpPutFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384170.aspx) documentation:

> `FtpPutFile` is a high-level routine that handles all the bookkeeping and overhead associated with reading a file locally and storing it on an FTP server. **An application that needs to send file data only, or that requires close control over the file transfer, should use the `FtpOpenFile` and `InternetWriteFile` functions**.

As well as in WinInet's [FTP Sessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384180.aspx) documentation

> **To upload or place files on an FTP server, the application can use either `FtpPutFile` or `FtpOpenFile` (along with `InternetWriteFile`)**. `FtpPutFile` can be used if the file already exists locally, while `FtpOpenFile` and `InternetWriteFile` can be used if data needs to be written to a file on the FTP server.

`Gdiplus::Bitmap` can save to either an HDD file or an `IStream`.  You can use 
either [`CreateStreamOnHGlobal()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378980.aspx) or [`SHCreateMemStream()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831.aspx) to create a memory stream, then save the `Bitmap` to the stream, and finally upload the content of the stream using `FtpOpenFile()` and `InternetWriteFile()`.

For example (error handling omitted for brevity, don't omit it in your real code!):

```
tmp = sDate + pictureName + ".jpeg";
wstring wtmp = ToStringW(tmp);
IStream *strm = SHCreateMemStream(NULL, 0);

using namespace Gdiplus;

GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

CLSID clsid;
GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
EncoderParameters encoderParameters;
encoderParameters.Count = 1;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Guid = EncoderQuality;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Type = EncoderParameterValueTypeLong;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].NumberOfValues = 1;

// Save the image as a JPEG with quality level 80.
ULONG quality = 80;
encoderParameters.Parameter[0].Value = &quality;

HDC scrdc = ::GetDC(0);
int Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
int Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(scrdc);
HBITMAP membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(scrdc, Width, Height);
HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP) SelectObject(memdc, membit);
BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, scrdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

{
Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(membit, NULL);
bitmap.Save(strm, &clsid); //saving the file to HDD
}

SelectObject(memdc, hOldBitmap);
DeleteObject(membit);
DeleteDC(memdc);
::ReleaseDC(0, scrdc);

GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

LARGE_INTEGER li;
li.QuadPart = 0;
strm->Seek(li, STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL);

//send to ftp with given info
saveFTP(server, user, password, wtmp.c_str(), strm);
strm->Release();
```

```
bool saveFTP(LPCWSTR l_server, LPCWSTR l_user, LPCWSTR l_pass, LPCWSTR l_ftpfile, IStream *l_screen)
{
    HINTERNET internet = InternetOpen(L"tester", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
    HINTERNET conn = InternetConnect(internet, l_server, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, l_user, l_pass, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, 0, 0);
    HINTERNET file = FtpOpenFile(conn, l_ftpfile, GENERIC_WRITE, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);

    BYTE buffer[1024], *pbuf;
    ULONG ulRead;
    DWORD dwWritten;
    HRESULT hr;
    bool success = true;

    do
    {
        hr = l_screen->Read(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &ulRead);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            success = false;
            break;
        }

        pbuf = buffer;
        while (ulRead != 0)
        {
            if (!InternetWriteFile(file, pbuf, ulRead, &dwWritten))
            {
                success = false;
                break;
            }
            pbuf += dwWritten;
            ulRead -= dwWritten;
        }
    }
    while (hr == S_OK);

    InternetCloseHandle(file);
    InternetCloseHandle(conn);
    InternetCloseHandle(internet);

    return success;
}
```

Comment: thank you for reply Remy. now i must replace  result = FtpPutFile(inter, l_screen, l_ftpfile, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0);
InternetCloseHandle(inter);
InternetCloseHandle(internet);      with      result = FtpOpenFile()(inter, l_screen, l_ftpfile, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY, 0); InternetWriteFile(inter);
InternetCloseHandle(inter);
InternetCloseHandle(internet);

Comment: Can you tell me please what arguments i must write in my code for:  InternetWriteFile(
    __in HINTERNET hFile,
    __in_bcount(dwNumberOfBytesToWrite) LPCVOID lpBuffer,
    __in DWORD dwNumberOfBytesToWrite,
    __out LPDWORD lpdwNumberOfBytesWritten
    );

Comment: Thank you Sir! I have only one error in first part of code : SHCreateMemStream undefined.

Comment: @snowman if you read the documentation I linked to, you need to use `#include <Shlwapi.h>` in your code and link to `Shlwapi.lib`.

Comment: i'm sorry, i am newbie.  I fix it by adding  #include <Shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")                                                                                 But now I have an unresolved external:  Error 9 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl saveFTP(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)" (?saveFTP@@YA_NPB_W0000@Z) D:\picsupload\main.obj

Comment: Now work!! Transfer is fine, but there is somting wrong with picture: have only 6kb and can't be open,says "Can't read file header"

Comment: I solved the pic issue, i replace .jpg with .png in this line:  GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &Clsid);  Now its fine, but the size is big, 2MB....   And second thing: how can i made the FTP server to enter always in passive mode? In server I have enabled 'Pasive mod settings' and check the ports range. Can we sent a PASV command from client side(C++)?

Comment: @snowman GDI+ supports JPG, did you verify "image/jpeg" was returning a valid CLSID, and `Save()` was not failing? As for `PASV`, you can specify the `INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE` flag on `InternetConnect()`: "*If `dwService` is `INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP`, `INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE` causes the application to use passive FTP semantics.*"

Comment: You are right again. Working! Now, I test it and i have a little issue with pictures, screens made by me are same like my desktop, but for my friend  PC the screens are incomplete like in this draw: http://prntscr.com/dvr7lj How can be fixed?

Comment: seem is the limatation of the Gdi+ the incomplete print screen from above link. Now a improvment: after the picture is uploaded to FTP how can I bring to front from taskbar, a minimezed aplication, for example notepad++ ?